# How to work with samples of variable length using keras for an RNN?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

## Background

Hello everyone,

I'm working on (what I thought would be) a simple RNN using Google Colab [Tensorflow 2.9.2 and Keras 2.9.0]. I've been working through this for a while now, but I can't quite seem to get everything to play nice. The inputs to my RNN are sequences of the numbers 0 ~ 6 inclusive expressed as one-hot-encoded column vectors. The targets are just a single 0 ~ 6 value expressed as a one-hot-encoded row vector.

[This link to a screenshot of my Colab describes...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrdFa.png)

- Input of [0] -> Target of 6
- Input of [0, 6] -> Target of 0
- Input of [0, 6, 0, 3] -> Target of 0
- Input of [0, 6, 0, 3, 0] -> Target of 5

From what I've been able to gather from other stackoverflow questions, blog posts, keras documentation, etc., the code below should be close to all I need for my use case as far as my model is concerned.

```
# Bulding RNN Model
model = None
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input((None, 7)))
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32)))
model.add(layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

# Compiling RNN Model
model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    optimizer="sgd",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
```

## The Problem

I'm very sure that my issue is related to every sample input being a vector or matrix of a different size. For example, a sequence of [0] would become a (7, 1) vector input for that particular timestep while [0, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3] would become a (7, 6) matrix input for its respective timestep. Based on the error messages I've received for the last several hours, I know keras isn't too pleased with that, but for what I'm trying to do, I'm not entirely sure of the best way forward.

I've manually split up my training and test sets.

( [Image of code with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/018qM.png) )

For clarity...

- x_train and x_test -> A list of numpy arrays each with a variable column count (e.g., np.shape=(7, ???))
- y_train and y_test -> A list of numpy arrays each with a constant size (e.g., np.shape=(1,7))

[I'm quite sure my types are correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiypb.png)

I'm fitting my model without anything extravagant.

```
# Fitting the RNN Model
model.fit(
    x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs = 50
)
```

That said, I continue to receive a Value Error saying that "Layer Sequential_??? expects 1 input(s), but it received ??? input tensors."

( [Image of Value Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgmrp.png) )

Any help at all in this matter would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needing a masking layer to for what I was trying to do.

Rather, I believe a masking layer solved two underlying problems...

1. My dimensions not being precisely what Keras wanted [samples, timestep, features]
2. Not knowing how to make my input structure work when every sample had a variable timestep value. I can't shake the feeling that there's still a way to do it without padding, but my model can now 'fit' for the first time in hours. So, I'm going to call this success on some level.

[Link to Embeddings and Masking](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding)

*With a special shoutout to [keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/pad_sequences)